# SQL to exclude results if a condition is met?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table: `compare`. I need to do an inner join with a `products` table:

```
idCompare idProduct dateStamp
1         1         2011-12-12
2         1         2011-12-10
3         1         2012-01-05
```

I want to exclude the idproduct's from my results if any of them have a date within say 7 days.

I've tried using the NOT IN and NOT EXISTS without success

```
SELECT     products.idProduct
FROM         products INNER JOIN
             compare ON products.idProduct = compare.idProduct
WHERE
(products.idProduct = '1') AND (products.idProduct 
    NOT IN
    (SELECT     idProduct
    FROM          compare
    WHERE      (products.idProduct = compare.idProduct) AND
    (dateStamp < DATEADD(DAY, - 7, GETDATE()))))
```

Comment: You're selecting `products.idProduct`, even though you define it as being `1`. Is this intentional?

Comment: I was just testing this 1 example, eventually I'll remove (products.idProduct = '1')

Comment: Don't you need to join `ON products.idProduct = compare.idProduct`?  Also you want `>` or `>=` instead of `<` in the last line, don't you?

Comment: And do you actually need the information in `compare`, or are you just trying to exclude the `product` if the comparison row exists?

Comment: Yep thats a typo, I had changed the table names etc from what I was using here. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could look like this:

```
SELECT p.idProduct
FROM   products AS p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   compare AS c
   WHERE  c.idProduct = p.idProduct
   AND    c.dateStamp BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, - 7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
   )
```

Don't `JOIN` to the table `compare`  in addition. Checking with `NOT EXISTS` is enough according to your description.

Comment: This will select products without a comparison at all, which the original won't.

Comment: Yep your right, no join needed! This is the more efficient answer. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your `not exists`:

```
select
    *
from
    products p
    inner join compare c on
        p.idProduct = c.idProduct
where
    not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            compare c2
        where
            c2.idProduct = p.idProduct
            and c2.datestamp between dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) and getdate()
    )
```

Comment: You caught the mismatch on the join condition.